# user profile informations

Tags: development, user-profile

How can I select the custom user profile information?

When I apply this code, I only reach the AD user profile information, but I have some additional user information. How can I reach them?

```
u[PropertyConstants.Manager].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
u["MyCustomProperty"].Value.ToString();
```

Or I have misunderstood your question. :)

Comment: nope its right :) thnks